# What is the point of the ellipses in react-hook-form register?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

In the documentation for react-hook-form packages, specifically, the [register](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Registerfields) section, it shows the following notation:

```html
    <input {...register("firstName")} />
```

So my question is what is the purpose of the ellipses here? Why isn't it enough for us to only do register(...) ?

Thanks

Comment: This is Javascript's [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax. `input` is an HTML element, not a Reactjs component. [register](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) returns multiple attributes that need to be passed to it, like `name`, events and a hook reference. The spread syntax breaks the return value into its components, so they can be rendered as individual attributes

Comment: Ohh okay, got it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

register return multiple values and methods, that you pass to standard html input

Spread is js syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

So the next two examples are the same:

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName'); 
// include type check against field path with the name you have supplied.
        
<input 
  onChange={onChange} // assign onChange event 
  onBlur={onBlur} // assign onBlur event
  name={name} // assign name prop
  ref={ref} // assign ref prop
/>
```

```
// same as above
<input {...register('firstName')} />
```